# Remove strings regardless of capitalization in Python

Tags: python, pandas

new to Python!

I have a dataset that has a variable called "PT_DISCH_DISPO". One of the options options is selected per record.

```
HOME/SELF CARE OP             
Admitted as inpatient         
PARENT HOME/SELF CARE IP       
LEFT WITHOUT TREATMENT         
TRANS TO OTHER FACILITY OP      
LEFT AGAINST MED ADVICE OP      
EXPIRED OTHER                   
DSCHRG/TRNSFR PSYCH IP          
FOSTER HOME IP                   
OTHER IP
```

I would like to write a datastep that removes records that are either EXPIRED OTHER, FOSTER HOME IP or LEFT WITHOUT TREATMENT. Now I know I can copy and paste the exact strings to remove these records, but I know I will be working with more complex/messy data down the road. Thus, I want to write a code that will remove each of these records based on a portion of the string and have the code not dependent on capitalization.

To start, I tried to write a code just to remove based on string but I get the following error:

```
TAT_v2 = np.where(~TAT_v1.PT_DISCH_DISPO.str.contains('LEFT','FOSTER,'EXPIRED')]


  File "C:\Users\gbond\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 930, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)

   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Once, I figure out this error, I would like to add to the code where it would still remove the strings even if the capitalization is not matching.

ANSWER:

```
TAT_v2 = TAT_v1.PT_DISCH_DISPO.str.lower().str.contains('left|foster|expired')
TAT_v3=TAT_v1[~s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to convert all of them to lower/upper case:

```
s = df.PT_DISCH_DISPO.str.lower().str.contains('left|foster|expired')
df[~s]
```

Output:

```
                     PT_DISCH_DISPO
0    HOME/SELF CARE OP             
1    Admitted as inpatient         
2   PARENT HOME/SELF CARE IP       
4  TRANS TO OTHER FACILITY OP      
7  DSCHRG/TRNSFR PSYCH IP          
9                          OTHER IP
```

Comment: Thanks!  The code that worked was                                                                               
TAT_v2 = TAT_v1.PT_DISCH_DISPO.str.lower().str.contains('left|foster|expired')
TAT_v3=TAT_v1[~s]        I was playing around with this and switched the "~s" with "~a" and got an error, why can it only be "~s"?

Comment: It need not be `~s`: if you assign `a = df.PT....` then it can be `~a`.

Answer (score 2):

`contains('LEFT','FOSTER','EXPIRED')` is an incorrect use of the function. Only the first parameter is interpreted as the pattern. The correct use is `contains('LEFT|FOSTER|EXPIRED', case=False)`.